# Swipe Gesture in Tabbed View App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So this is very, very weird. I've added a Swipe Gesture Recognizer from the starboards into the view for the first tab in my 6-tab tab bar.  I set it to the left direction and connected it as an Action to the firstTabViewController.h. And it works perfectly.

Now, if I try to add the "right direction" Swipe Gesture recognizer to this first tab in the same way, the action doesn't even register.

Also, if I try to do the same thing in another one of the tabs (not the one at index 0), or move the working tab to a different position in the tab bar, the app crashes with a  bad access error when I swipe.

firstTabViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender;   // Works fine
- (IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender;  // Doesn't even register
```

firstTabViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender {
    int nextIndex = CURRENT_INDEX + 1;  // I did modify this accordingly when the tab was moved

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:nextIndex];
    NSLog(@"Swipe left");

}

- (IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Swiped Right");
}
```

Comment: can you please post the code for initializing the swipegesture object?

Comment: Maybe thats what I'm missing, I don't know how that would look. All I did was drag and drop the "Swipe Gesture Recognizer" item onto the view with storyboards. And then I Control-dragged an IBAction connection from that icon to my viewController.h

Comment: please make sure, you added two swipe gesture recognizer objects in the view. Have specified the direction of the gestures left and right respectively. And connected the IBActions correctly...

Comment: Apparently that was what I was missing. I had assumed that the storyboard/Ctrl-drag connections would initialize what I needed, but looks like another example of relying too much on technology. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested this and it works:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
swipeLeft.delegate = self;
[swipeLeft release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
swipeRight.delegate = self;
[swipeRight release];

-(void) swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
        NSLog(@"swipe right");
}

-(void) swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
        NSLog(@"swipe left");

}
```

Comment: Where did you put *swipeLeft and *swipe Right? In the IBAction, ViewDidLoad, or somewhere else?

Comment: viewDidLoad -- you should literally be able to copy and paste that code into your viewDidLoad and those methods and it should work

Comment: Works great! However, should I be concerned about the warnings: `Assigning to 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'firstViewController *'` on the line `swipeLeft.delegate = self;`

Comment: It's because your view controller class doesn't conform to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.  I don't see anything in Shabzco's code that uses any of the delegate protocol methods, and I suspect you're not using them either, so you should be good to just delete that line.

Comment: It's worth a note on this, that you can use the same method (keeps the logic together for me) for both recognizers, and just check recognizer.direction